# Visual Studio 2015 hangs on Create Declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide

I am working on a small C++ project in Visual Studio Community Edition 2015. It contains about 4 units and has two outside libraries connected. Everything was working fine but after some random point in time IDE started to completely hang after using the Create Declaration option from the Quick Actions menu. The cursor stays as it was, which is vertical bar and nothing else happens, it doesn't even say Not Responding. This happens to any project.

I have tried deleting the .suo file and restarting the computer. Nothing helps.

Comment: How about switching to VS2017?

Comment: @VTT That's actually a good idea, but won't do in the middle of my projects.